# Apache mod_auth_sspi with virtual hosts

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, virtualhost

I've a problem with the mod_auth sspi module of apache when using Virtual Hosts. The problem is about the login prompts.

This is is the configuration of my httpd-vhosts.conf File

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/Web/test"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "c:/Web/test">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthName "Protected"
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    #SSPIOmitDomain On
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

If I call

```
http://localhost/test
```

in my browser, everything is working fine. I'll get the username in the $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] variable. I don't have to type my username and password in the prompt-window. But if I call

```
http://test.localhost
```

I always have to type username and password in the login-mask.

I have also put the sites to the intranet-zone in IE-settings.

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SSPI sites need to be trusted in the browser you use.
That's why it may work for localhost, but not for test.localhost

In Internet Explorer you can define e.g. all intranet sites to be trusted.
In Firefox you can use network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris

Comment: Do you know if there is another workaround to this problem for all this time?